# Accessing `_holderTokens` private method in ERC721 contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, nft

I'd like to have a page on my NFT site that shows which tokens a specific address owns. So if I own 10 NFTs for FoobarContract, I'd like to be able to show those 10 NFTs on this page.

It seems there's a private mapping in the ERC721 contract called `_holderTokens` with a description of `Mapping from holder address to their (enumerable) set of owned tokens`. Perfect. This is exactly what I need to access. But it's only accessible through the contract, and every other exposed public method that accesses it only gives me things like `balanceOf`, which isn't useful in this case, and `tokenOfOwnerByIndex`, which is also useless to me.

Am I missing something? This is one of the most important pieces of data in the ERC721 contract, yet it's inaccessible when inheriting from it. How else does someone go about getting the 10 tokens that this hypothetical address owns? I've searched for other solutions, but they all say to pull in all events and filter them down to a particular receiving address and do the math to figure out which tokens are in this address's possession. Isn't this an absurd waste of resources when the mapping is literally right there in the contract?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate a mapping.

Your two choices are to:

1. Implement `ERC721Enumerable` which is designed to make this specific use case as simple as possible.
2. Do not implement `ERC721Enumerable` and use an archival node to listen to all `Transfer` events to catalog the tokens.